# Number of inversions from the inversion table

Tags: combinatorics

In Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics", he claims in the proof of colloray 1.3.13 that "If $I(w) = (a_1,...,a_n)$, then $inv(w) = a_1+...+a_n$. I don't really see why this is true, could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows almost immediately from the observation made just after the example in which Stanley explains $I(w)$:

> Clearly $a_i$ is the number of entries $j$ of $w$ to the left of $i$ satisfying $j>i$.

In other words, $a_i$ is the number of pairs $\langle j,i\rangle$ of elements of $w$ such that $j$ is to the left of $i$ **and** $j>i$. Those pairs are precisely the inversions of $w$ having $i$ as their second element. Each inversion of $w$ has exactly one $i\in[n]$ as its second element. Thus, $a_1+a_2$ is the number of inversions of $w$ having $1$ or $2$ as second element, $a_1+a_2+a_3$ is the number having $1$ or $2$ or $3$ as second element, and so on. In particular, we can sum over all possible second elements to find that

$$\operatorname{inv}(w)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\;.$$

The observation that I highlighted is a direct consequence of the definition of $I(w)$. We insert elements of $[n]$ into the table in descending order. When we insert $k$ into the string, the $n-k$ larger members of $[n]$ have already been inserted, and we place $k$ so that $a_k$ of them are to its left. The remaining numbers to be added to the string are all smaller than $k$, so those $a_k$ numbers are the *only* numbers larger than $k$ that end up on the left of $k$. Thus, $a_k$ is indeed the number of entries $j$ to the left of $k$ that are bigger than $k$, and hence the number of inversions having $k$ as second element.